# Hadoop: How to compile libhdfs.so?

Tags: c++, ant, hadoop

We are using Hadoop through the Hadoop C/C++ API (libhdfs.so). We use the latest stable Hadoop version which is 0.20.203. Unfortunately, there are no clear (and up to date) instructions to build libhdfs.so. When I try to build Hadoop with ant, it fails and does not build the libhdfs.so library.

Tried using the following:

```
ant -Dcompile.c++=true -Dlibhdfs=true compile-c++-libhdfs
```

It seems to fail at line 1761 of build.xml. At this line there is the following xml:

```
<exec executable="${c++.libhdfs.src}/configure" dir="${build.c++.libhdfs}"
          failonerror="yes">
```

Does anyone have instructions to build libhdfs.so on Ubuntu 64bit 10.10 ?

Comment: does configure exists and has executable right for the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It was failing because the configure had already been executed and I needed to do a "make dist clean" in the "src/c++/libhdfs" directory before building the library. Now it works as expected using:

```
ant -Dcompile.c++=true -Dlibhdfs=true compile-c++-libhdfs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on hadoop-2.7.2 you can make use of cmake under hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src:

`cmake -DJAVA_HOME=<your_jdk_path> -DGENERATED_JAVAH=<your_jdk_path> -DJAVA_JVM_LIBRARY=<your_jdk_path/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so> -DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=<your_jdk_path/include> -DJAVA_INCLUDE_PATH=<your_jdk_path/include/linux>`

Then it will generate makefile for you. Then you do: 
`make`

Comment: Could you state, how this relates to the solution, the OP provided himself more than 4 years ago ;-) maybe why it is better, if that is the case. It is stated, that a make dist clean suffices ... why should be a cmake "better". Thanks.